# Worker Role WCF Performance

Tags: wcf, azure

I am trying to determine the best performing WCF service hosting scenario possible. I am assembling a very high volume, on-premise web app (which will eventually be hosted in Azure). The ASP.Net app will communicate with WCF services hosted in worker roles using NetTcpBinding. I would like verification on the following assumptions:

1) Hosting the services in worker roles, then using the Service Bus (using ACS for security) to connect client and service will always be slower than hosting WCF services in worker roles, connecting directly to the endpoint, and using a username/password approach.

2) REST services will always be slower than NetTcpBinding services because they use HTTP instead of binary.

Initially, I opted for the the ServiceBus approach because I like how clean the security mechanism is, but unless the ongoing connection can be Direct, the relay will cause significant overhead.

Based on these assumption, I have opted for:
-WCF Services hosted in worker roles
-custom Username/Password or use ACS username/password??????
-NetTcpBinding

Does this sound about right? Another requirement is the least amount of security specific code I need to create. So, should I use the ACS username/password model or????

any insight on how to setup the best performing, least custom code security would be great!

thanks

Answer (score 2):

First: benchmark, benchmark, benchmark. We were quite surprised at the performance characteristics of Azure; in particular SQL Azure was slower than our Rackspace hosted system by a factor of two or three. The latency between the database and the server eclipsed everything else.

That said: in theory I'd confirm your guess that using usernames/passwords between client and service will be faster than ACS.

But do you need to do any credential checking at all? Can you use private internal endpoints (as here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432980.aspx) -- if so then there's no need for any credential checking.

If you do need to expose a public endpoint then I'd seriously consider using client SSL certificates instead as this can provide encryption as well as authentication.

Regarding REST versus binary, much depends on the kind of application you're working with. My experience with the Microsoft REST stack is that it's remarkably efficient: in practice by the time the connection is established and data is flowing you basically have a raw TCP connection between client and server. What you gain with REST, however, is the HTTP semantics, ability to use load balancers, and general convenience.

But, again: I'd create some sample applications and test for yourself. (And do come back and post a link to your blog entry where you publish the results, eh?)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. The issue with internal endpoints is that they cannot be used until the web app is hosted within Azure, initially, it won't. Your findings on the latency between the db and the server is interesting. I will absolutely post my findings. Thanks for the post!

Comment: Well this is interesting:"Windows Azure provides load balancing across each public endpoint, allowing you to scale your application to as many instances as you'd like. You need to ensure that your application is stateless (or stores state in a common area across instances, such as blobs or tables). The only endpoints not load-balanced are internal endpoints. So, if you're doing some type of inter-role communication, like from a web role to one of several worker role instances hosting a wcf service on an internal endpoint, you'd need to handle load balancing across those instances." SO posting

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the ACL unless you really need it, which I don't think it's your scenario. Adding an additional broker just for authenticating the clients will add an unnecessary latency. Secondly, you don't need a worker role for using NetTcp, you can just configure a web role with a tcp endpoint. That will host your service in IIS using WAS and TCP. You can even configure the WCF Services in a private endpoint in azure that only the web application also hosted in azure can see, so no authentication is needed.